# What options are available within AWS API Gateway to authenticate on-prem client requests to private APIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I'm looking to setup an AWS **API Gateway** which will have private APIs (internal business client apps only)

One of the client apps that will be making requests to 1 of the apis is a client that is on-prem.

What options are available to authenticate requests coming from a client when that client is on-prem? Is there some type of tunnel I am able to create between the on-prem client on AWS VPC?

I dont want to at all make the APIs public. So I want to continue to keep all apis private. Any and all insights appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The following tools are provided to enhance the security of API Gateway.

Firstly there's support for a [private API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html). By doing this it will only be accessible from the VPC and devices connected via VPN or Direct Connect to the API Gateway.

If it must be publicly accessible, but kept private you can lockdown he endpoint via either an [API Gateway Resource Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html) or by attaching a [WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-aws-waf.html) to your API Gateway.

Finally if you need more advanced methods of authenticating and providing authorization to specific routes in your API, then you should look at API Gateways feature of [Lambda Authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html).

Comment: Thank you Mokugo, so can you please summarize exactly which option I can leverage for my use case specifically?

Comment: So the question is, must the API be public and by authenticate what do you mean? Is there custom logic or simply it must be limited to a number of IP addresses?

Comment: My question is specifically: How can I make an on-prem client make a request to a private API gateway. My best guess at this point is AWS Direct Connect?

Comment: So if it must be private, use a VPN or Direct Connect if you feel that the cost is worth it. Also deploy the API explicitely as a private API

Comment: VPN or Direct Connect? From what I understand, having a VPN is a hard requirement of having private API gateway apis. Are you saying its an either-or option here? Again, my best guess here is that its simply "Use Direct Connect".

Comment: VPN and Direct Connect will provide similar options. Direct Connect provides dedicated throughput whereas a VPN traverses the internet. Direct connect is generally more expensive and requires dedicated infrastructure being set up at your on premise.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the simple answer is:

Option 1: Use **Direct Connect**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html

[image]
*or*

Option 2: Use **AWS Site-to-Site VPN**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html